# UI testing Blazor Dekstop apps

Tags: blazor, ui-testing, blazor-desktop

I'm really interested in making the next project in MAUI with WebView hosting Blazor app.

I know that I can use [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/) to unit test components, but is there a solution to run full UI tests like in Cypress?

I mean literally running the app, and have something click around. Or is bUnit enough? Is it able to run MAUI app with all native services (like opening a file from disk with a native popup) or do I need to mock the edge services?

I came with an alternative which would be to setup a server side Blazor poject running the same app and just use Cypress, but I don't really like this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone wondering, Playwrite has a dotnet API and works pretty nice: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/